# JDBC Driver return wrong value from mysql

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, node.js, jdbc

i using **jdbc driver** (node-jdbc) for getting schema using node js

row data :

[image]

i have already tried and got this result in console ( https://prnt.sc/umlb7m )

[image]

why i got wrong return value with float type?

or can i parse this float data type?

that i want is getting a real float value from table, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to store numbers with exact precision, but you are using a floating point data type instead, such as `FLOAT`, `REAL`, or `DOUBLE`.

Define the column `amount` as `DECIMAL`.

For example, if you need 6 places at the left of the decimal point, and one at the right, you can use `DECIMAL(7,1)`. In this type you can store values such as `1.0` or `123456.7`.

Comment: if using type orm there's no problem with that.
https://prnt.sc/umuj3w

the problem is about jdbc driver